# Reconnecting iPad after iTunes have forgotten it without wiping contents

Tags: itunes, ios, icloud

I have several iDevices each used by a different person. I have set up all iDevices to use the same Apple ID for purchasing apps but each iDevice to have a separate Apple ID for iCloud (which is [allowed according to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895))

However I did not know that running this way you have to sync each iDevice to a different iTunes installation (according to [this elucidating article on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5850167/configure-icloud-for-multiple-apple-ids))

So, I have one computer (Windows 7 64bit) with iTunes that I previously used to sync both an iPhone 4 and an iPad 1.

1. I first upgraded the iPad 1 to iOS5 and synced it. Worked fine
   (over wifi too)
2. I then upgraded the iPhone 4 to iOS5 and synced it.
   Worked fine (over wifi too)
3. Then, when I connected the iPad again, iTunes no longer
   recognized the iPad. I got several errors:
   *iTunes could not connect     to this iPad because an unknown error occurred (0xE800007F)* and 
   *An iPad has been detected but it could not be identified properly. Please disconnect and reconnect the iPad, then try again.*
4. Finally iTunes showed the *Set Up Your iPad* screen

I do not want to *Set Up Your iPad* since I assume that that would wipe the current configuration of it.
Since learning that I must sync with a separate iTunes for each iDevice, I have decided that I would like to sync the iPhone 4 with another iTunes.

How can I (after moving the iPhone 4) "reconnect" the iPad to the same iTunes without wiping its contents?
(I am also not completely sure on how to "move" the iPhone 4, so that it no longer is synced with the iTunes installation that I want the iPad to be connected to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I assumed wrong. Thanks to kenansulayman's answer, I dared to continue after the "Set Up Your iPad" screen. When I did, iTunes did not wipe the iPad, it left the old configuration unaltered and started syncing normally.

Also, "moving" the iPhone was fairly straightforward. I just unchecked the "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi" on the old computer, synced it with the new and checked "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi" there.

Comment: I had the same issue and same resolution. Clicking on "continue" on the "Set Up Your iPad" screen took me to a screen where, to be safe, I unclicked all the auto-syncing options and then I was able to get into the iPad without losing any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the iOS 5, make an iCloud-Backup from your device, then wipe it, finally restore from iCloud and you're good to go.

This won't break anything and is pretty much fail-safe. (It worked in beta, too - and saved both my iTouch and iPad from wiping once)

Comment: The only way to not "wipe" it would be to break it and manually copy the data from the device. In this state, iTunes's pretty much paranoid and the only real solution is the iCloud-save'n'restore. (Since the device knows itself.. and can directly backup the appropriate content)